# How to filter request to api-gateway's controller in api-gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I use a custom api-gateway for services and my gateway has a controller (for handling rest request making a grpc request to another service).
Also I have a CustomGlobalFilter for filtering rest requests. It works good for routes, but doesn't work for requests to api-gateway controller. I need to handle and filter requests from front to *all services including api-gateway* in **one** CustomGlobalFilter.
We have tried to change @Order and endpoint-api.
Routes configuration includes Api-gateway's apis.

Any suggestions? Did anyone face such kind of problem, if so how did solve it?

Comment: Global filters only are run if a gateway route is matched. Otherwise you need to use a webflux WebFilter.

Answer (score 1):

spencergibb in a comment is right!

(Global filters only are run if a gateway route is matched. Otherwise you need to use a webflux WebFilter.)

I have changed GlobalFilter to WebFilter, so now my CustomFilter implements WebFilter and it's working.

Thank you, [spencergibb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2730527/spencergibb)